# Not getting proper response in the tree table after performing login scenario using JMeter

Tags: https, jmeter, performance-testing, load-testing

I just started to use JMeter with the tutorial (for a sample website), which returns clear response data.

But, when I started to use in one of my projects, I saw the response was encrypted in `View results in tree`.

So can anyone provide solution for it? This was the response i was getting

[image: Response in table tree]

Comment: I don't think its encrypted data. It looks like output of file download, If its encrypted data, Is it the same way displayed in browser?

Comment: @ Selvakumar Ponnusamy,The above displayed output comes when i performed login scenario

Comment: 1. Try using Text view instead of HTML. 2. Check if you have enabled follow redirects. This seems to be some ajax response.

Comment: @rachnabafna, I tried with every option like using 'Text, HTML, Json' every response was like this only. Till login the response was readable, once logged in the response was like above shown. If your system is configured with jMeter you can try with GitHub login. Coming back to your second point  its already checked/enabled

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I doubt you haven't check marked '**Use this proxy server for all protocols**' while creating manual proxy configuration. By checking/ ticking that check box it will allow you to record the scenarios and also it gives you a proper response.

and I also doubt that you are getting proper server name. By doing the above step it will solve your problem